# Frequency response terminology: $N(i\omega)$, $Q(i\omega)$

Tags: power-spectral-density, frequency-response, random-process

I am reading through an analysis of a system
$$
Y(t) = \frac{d}{dt}X(t) + X(t)
$$
and the frequency response $H(i\omega)$ is defined as
$$
H(i\omega) = \frac{N(i\omega)}{Q(i\omega)} = \frac{1+i\omega}{1}
$$

(In this case, $i$ is the imaginary number.)

Is there a term for the functions $N$ and $Q$ used here?

Additionally, the author states
$$
S_Y(\omega) = |H(i\omega)|^2S_X(\omega)
$$
Is there a reason the frequency is multiplied by the imaginary number within the squared frequency response, but not within the spectral density functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically a transfer function is described as a function of the complex variable $s$ as given by the Laplace Transform of the systems impulse response:

$$H(s)= \frac{N(s)}{Q(s)}$$

By expressing the transfer function of a linear system as a ratio of two such polynomials, we are able to describe the linear system uniquely in terms of the roots of those polynomials, where we would call the roots of the numerator polynomial ($N(i\omega)$) the zeros of the system and the root of the denominator polynomial ($Q(i\omega$)) the poles of the system. This reduced and compact description (the system poles and zeros) completely describes those polynomials and the system and allows for further simplified evaluation of system parameters, such as stability by confirming that all poles are in the left half plane. $s$ has real and imaginary components as $s = \sigma + i \omega$, and when we restrict $s$ to be just the imaginary axis ($i \omega$) we then arrive at the frequency response as well from that same original form:

$$H(i \omega) = \frac{N(i \omega)}{Q(i \omega)}$$

The magnitude function for complex variables is computed with a complex conjugate multiplication:

$$|H(i\omega)| = \sqrt{(H(i\omega) H^*(i\omega)}$$

For this reason power spectral densities as $S_X(\omega)$ and $S_Y(\omega)$ and power terms in general are always real and have no imaginary components (excluding cross-power spectral densities).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they get a special name -just the numerator and denominator function.

Notice that the frequency response is defined as the ratio of output spectrum to input spectrum, but since the input signal is called X and the output Y, I don't think N and Q have a direct relationship with them (lest you're omitting some context from the material where you took this from).

---

The notation with the complex unit in the frequency argument is just convention. I've seen this in books that are Control Theory-centric; makes sense, as the Fourier transform is a bilateral infinite Laplace transform with the Laplace-domain variable being purely imaginary, I.e. $s=i\omega$.